# python + go через c

Tags: python, c, golang

Недавно заинтересовался объединением python и go (например для ускорения каких-либо задач). Я нашёл пару сайтов на эту тему, но выяснилось, что для их объединения нужен `c`. Прошу помощи: объясните человеку, который не знает `c`, где нужно сделать <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> для того, чтобы написанная на go функция вызывалась из python и отдавала результат.

P.S: сайты: [1](https://www.swe-notes.ru/post/go-python-module/), [2](https://words.filippo.io/building-python-modules-with-go-1-5/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Функции оформляешь в пакет `main`. Минимально выглядит так sum.go:

```
package main

import "C"

//export Sum
func Sum(a, b int) int {
        return a + b
}

func main() {}
```

`//export Sum` строчка обязательна, без неё python не увидит функцию через си.

Компилишь таким способом:

```
go build -o sum.so -buildmode=c-shared sum.go
```

На выходе sum.so и sum.h. В sum.h смотри типы переменных.

С типами немного надо подробнее. Функция отображается как `extern GoInt Sum(GoInt a, GoInt b);` `GoInt` определение выше `typedef GoInt64 GoInt;`, `GoInt64` уже определенно как сишный тип `long long`, который в питоне преобразуется через `ctypes.c_longlong` в питонский `int`. В этом примере указание типа в питоне не обязательно, но если нужно передать что-то сложное понадобится.

В питоне загружется библиотека через ctypes:

```
import ctypes

lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("./sum.so")
lib.Sum.argtypes = [ctypes.c_longlong, ctypes.c_longlong]
print(lib.Sum(1,3))
```

## Работа со строками

### Через c char

Приводим строку к C.char в Го

```
//export Echo
func Echo(s *C.char) *C.char {
    return C.CString(
      strings.ToUpper(
        C.GoString(
          s
        )
      )
    )
}
```

И в питоне:

```
lib.Echo.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p]
lib.Echo.restype = ctypes.c_char_p

print(lib.Echo('hello'.encode()).decode())
```

Но тут надо быть осторожным в том плане что результат выданный через указатель не освобождает память. Надо проверить освобождает ли её Питон при удалении указателя.

### Через GoString

Если экспортировать функцию `func Echo(s string) string {return strings.ToUpper(s) }` то это может привести к проблемам со сборщиком мусора Go, а при вызове падает с ошибкой `panic: runtime error: cgo result has Go pointer`

Но входящие строки можно передать из питона так

```
class GoString(ctypes.Structure):
    "typedef struct { const char *p; ptrdiff_t n; } _GoString_;"
    def __init__(self, s):
        super().__init__(s.encode(), len(s))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.p.decode()

    _fields_ = [("p", ctypes.c_char_p),
                ("n", ctypes.c_size_t)]


lib.Echo.argtypes = [GoString]
lib.Echo(GoString('hello'))
```

Comment: А как передать строку? В argtypes я указал `ctypes.c_char_p`, но он всё равно ругается: `print(lib.TestFunc("test")) ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type`

Comment: покажи хедер какой получился.

Comment: Что такое хедер? `func TestFunc(str string) string {` это?

Comment: .h файл... попробую у себя, позже отпишусь

Comment: Огромное спасибо! В случае со строками сработал первый вариант. Может я что-то не так сделал, но во втором способе `lib.Echo(GoString('hello'))` мне возвращает `int`

Comment: во втором варианте я написал что возврат понормальному не сделаешь. gc от go ломает.

Comment: хотя если вернуло Int, то это указатель на строку и его можно забрать в структуру.

Comment: но скорее это просто прошлая версия библиотеки