# Как в проекте с Python использовать Go?

Tags: python, golang

Мне интересно как можно использовать Go в проекте на Python. Например, у меня есть сайт на Python(Django), и мне нужно сделать микросервис, например, для запросов на другие серверы. Т.е. как связать Python и Go. Если есть статьи или видео курсы на русском или английском, буду благодарен, если поделитесь ими)

Comment: Микросервисы подразумевают что у вас есть несколько отдельных аппок, которые общаются между собой каким-то IPC, например gRPC. В этом случае не важно, на чем написан каждый отдельный микросервис, важно чтобы они соблюдали протокол общения.

Comment: Если же вы хотите встроить в проект на питоне библиотеку на go, тут недавно мелькал вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1421679/python-go-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-c